# Using Django to install Google Analytics tracking code

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

**AIM**

Using Django to install Google Analytics.

**PROBLEM**

It isn't clear to me if I need to apply the following lines to ALL the templates I am interested in tracking or just to index.html.

```
{% load google_analytics_tags %}
<div style="display:none">
    <img src="{% google_analytics %}" width="0" height="0" />
</div>
```

If the answer is that by simply pasting it into index.html would add it to all my existing templates, how can I exclude the pages I don't want any tracking from?

I am following the steps from: https://pypi.org/project/django-google-analytics-app/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to create a seperate template called `analytics.html` and put your analytics code in this file then add the line

```
{% include "analytics.html" %}
```

to the files you want to track analytics for.

Comment: In that template called analytics.html I would paste the code exactly as it is in my question right? Including {% load google_analytics_tags %} ?

Comment: @Joehat I see that you are using https://pypi.org/project/django-google-analytics-app/ I have not personally used this library but according to their documentation seems like it should work.

Comment: I forgot to include the link to the question. I've just edited it. From that same link, in step 3. would I paste ```(r'^djga/', include('google_analytics.urls')),``` as it is in urls.py or should I paste it inside something else and in step 4. where would ```GOOGLE_ANALYTICS = {
    'google_analytics_id': 'xxx',
} ```go? Is it in settings.py ? Thanks you for help!

Comment: yes, you are right, the first part goes in `urls.py` and second in `settings.py`